# Create Functions with Parameters Returns - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im a bit confused or maybe just a lack of knowledge. Just doing my first steps. My question is: I need to test when a number pair (like 100, 5 let's say) will compare correctly as numbers and incorrectly as strings. How to fix it properly. I cant figure out the best way to test this last option.
1st test is Both numbers the same
2nd test is first number largest
3rd test is second number largest

I thought maybe I should say True to the first test. And say False when numbers as strings. ??

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
        alert(largest(false,false));
        alert(largest(true,false));
        alert(largest(false,true));
        alert();
    </script>
```

```
function largest (firstNum, secondNum) {
    let largestNumber = largest;
        firstNum = parseInt(prompt('Enter the first number: '));
        secondNum = parseInt(prompt('Enter the second number: '));
        if (firstNum == secondNum) {    //3
            return false;   ///  maybe True?.. see my question
        } else {
            if (firstNum > secondNum) {     //1
                return largest = firstNum;
            } else if (firstNum < secondNum) {     //2
                return largest = secondNum;
            }
        if (isNaN(firstNum, secondNum)) {        /// false if strings?  
            return false;
        }
        }
    return largestNumber;
}
}
```

Comment: `return largest = firstNum;` <-- Why are you setting largest? You are overriding the function with the number

Comment: strings does not make sense when you are converting it to a number

Comment: Why are you passing true and false when you are prompting????

Comment: ok.. I`ll try to clean up the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is doing so many things as I can see
It's returning true/false, largest number, etc.

I suggest you to clean up a bit your code like this!

```
function largest() {
    const firstNum = parseInt(prompt('Enter the first number: '));
    const secondNum = parseInt(prompt('Enter the second number: '));
    if (isNaN(firstNum) || isNaN(secondNum)) {
        alert('Invalid input!');
        return null;
        // return largest(); // This could work too
    }

    if (firstNum > secondNum) {
        return firstNum;
    }

    return secondNum;
}
```

First, we ask the user to input both numbers
Then, we check if the values are valid, `isNaN` helps us with that, and if there is something incorrect, we show and alert and return

If the numbers are valid, we check

If firstNumber is larger than secondNumber, the largest one should be firstNumber

Otherwise, we return secondNumber (Last case)

Comment: thanks..let see how that works.. i will modify my code

Comment: i have fix a bit and it works well.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't well formulated so I wasn't entirely sure, but I assumed you mean that the compare should only return `true` if it was based on a numerical comparison (i.e. any string input should return `false`

If that was your question you could try it like this:

```
const arr = [[100,5],["100",5],[100,"5"],["100", "5"]]

// return true if first value is bigger
function compare(v1, v2) {
    if (typeof(v1)==="string" || typeof(v2)==="string")
      return false;
    else
      return (v1 > v2);
}

// return array [boolean, boolean] for each of the input values
function acompare(v1, v2) {        
    if (typeof(v1)==="string" || typeof(v2)==="string")
      return [false, false, false];
    else
      return [(v1 > v2), (v1 < v2), (v1===v2)];
}

for (let a of arr) {
    console.log(compare(a[0],a[1]), acompare(a[0],a[1]))
}

//returns
//true, [true, false]
//false, [false, false]
//false, [false, false]
//false, [false, false]
```

see: https://jsfiddle.net/d2sv7xcb/5/

This way whenever either of the arguments is a string it returns false, if not it the returns the value of the comparison?

@Edit:
Following your comment I have added the `===` to the function return value, that way you get back an array for the comparison?

```
[false, false, false] = no valid comparison
[true, false, false] = value 1 > value 2
[false, true, false] = value 1 < value 2
[false, false, true] = value 1 === value 2
```

Comment: I need to test for the following cases:
- first number larger than second number
- second number larger than first number
- both numbers the same
- a number pair like 100, 5 which will compare correctly as numbers and incorrectly as strings.